# sql server cannot connect to windows 8

Tags: windows, sql-server-2008

I have a problem when i try to connect my SQL server 2008 express edition to visual studio 2010 and i was try to create web service.

When i am try to install server it show error message like it is not suit for windows 8 operating system.

but i can't connect my SQL server to windows 8 system.

i am using windows 64 bit operating system.

please fix my problem and please suggest correct  structure query language version for windows 8.

Thanks advance.....

Comment: Hello and Welcome to StackOverflow. Can you show us the error message please ? I'm assuming you're trying to open SQL management Studio ? or are you trying to view your databases in Visual Studio ?

Comment: No when i installing sql server 2008 express that time its shows this is not suit version for windows 8

Comment: Please refer to the following link. You may need to install a few patches .etc. before getting it to work.

http://forums.asp.net/t/1929271.aspx?Can+we+install+Sql+Server+2008+on+Windows+8+